No response from backend server placed in docker container
I have 3 docker containers configured in docker-compose-build.yml
mysql database, angular application and spring boot application
My frontend app dosn't get any response from the backend server and also there is absolutely no logs in backend application, but when i docker exec the frontend container and curl the same request as browser, I got the correct response, there are correct logs in backend application
When I run the project on my localhost not in docker container everything works
docker-compose-build.yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  noteapp-mysql:
    container_name: noteapp-mysql
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      - my-network
  noteapp-server:
    container_name: noteapp-server
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-spring
    depends_on:
      - noteapp-mysql
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=NotesAppApi
      - SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL=true
      - SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://noteapp-mysql:3306/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&autoReconnect=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=$MYSQLDB_USER
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_PASSWORD
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_DATABASE=mysql
      - SPRING_JPA_DATABASE-PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      - SPRING_MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - SPRING_MAIL_PORT=587
      - SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME=$MAIL_USERNAME
      - SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD=$MAIL_PASSWORD
      - SPRING_MAIL_PROPERTIES_MAIL_SMTP_AUTH=true
      - SPRING_MAIL_PROPERTIES_MAIL_SMTP_STARTTLS_ENABLE=true
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - my-network
  noteapp-client:
    container_name: noteapp-client
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-angular
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    depends_on:
      - noteapp-server
    networks:
        - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge


Dockerfile-angular
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY  NoteApp/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npx ngcc --properties es2023 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points
COPY NoteApp .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY NoteApp/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist/note-app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}


no response in the browser

the exact curl inside the frontend app container:

to deploy containers i use:
docker-compose -f docker-compose-build.yml up -d
I expected that there was a problem with cors, but my spring boot application allows all ip's to send requests:
cors configuration
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${api.base.path}")
    public static final String API_BASE_PATH = "/api";
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}

I thought that there is maybe a problem with the fact that I ran my application on top of the nginx server inside the frontend container, but I couldn't recognize any possible issues with nginx

FE application is being run on the client browser = not inside of the container. FE container only gives the files for the client to run your application

From the error screen shot it looks like you're trying to connect to the container name as a host name.  As @Andrei notes, the application is fundamentally running in the browser, even if its code is served from a container, and it can't reach the Docker-internal host names.  I'd add an HTTP path that proxy_pass to the backend container to your existing Nginx configuration, and then you can reach the backend with a path-only URL like /api without needing to know a host name.

Yes it works, I do it even before, but got misunderstood because blocked 8080 port of my remote server, and changed the url path
